# Associating a method with a struct that returns "self"

Tags: go

I understand that Go doesn't have traditional OOP concepts. However, I'd love to know whether there is a better way for designing a "constructor" as I've done it in my code snippet below:

```
type myOwnRouter struct {
}

func (mor *myOwnRouter) ServeHTTP(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    fmt.Fprintf(w, "Hello from my own Router!")
}

func newMyOwnRouter() *myOwnRouter {
    return &myOwnRouter{}
}

func init() {
    http.Handle("/", newMyOwnRouter())
    ...
}
```

I basically would like to get rid of the "stand alone" newMyOwnRouter() function and have it as part of the struct itself, for example I'd like to be able to do something like:

```
http.Handle("/", myOwnRouter.Router)
```

Is that doable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The defacto standard pattern is a function calle New

```
package matrix
function NewMatrix(rows, cols int) *matrix {
    m := new(matrix)
    m.rows = rows
    m.cols = cols
    m.elems = make([]float, rows*cols)
    return m
}
```

Of course the construct function must be a Public one, to be called outside of the package.

More about constructor pattern [here](http://www.golangpatterns.info/object-oriented/constructors)

In your case looks like you want a Sigleton package then this is the pattern:

```
package singleton

type myOwnRouter struct {
}

var instantiated *myOwnRouter = nil

func NewMyOwnRouter() * myOwnRouter {
    if instantiated == nil {
        instantiated = new(myOwnRouter);
    }

    return instantiated;
}
```

Comment: So that would always be on the package level, correct? It would then be matrix.NewMatrix(...). There is no way of doing anything like that on a struct level, am I right?

Comment: Nope this a "constructor" in go, the core pacakges use the same pattern: http://golang.org/src/pkg/os/exec/exec.go?s=3410:3455#L99

Comment: Thanks. Very well appreciated. One last question: In the sources you've linked to, they return the pointer (return &Cmd). If I take the code you've pasted, would I have to return &m and return &instantiated? Or is it correct the way you've written it here?

Comment: instantiated is already a pointer, in your code you are creating a instance and returning his pointer. http://www.golang-book.com/8

Comment: Sorry for being a pain... But return m does not return the pointer, or? Wouldn't it have to be return &m?

Comment: If I would have done m := matrix{...} I would have needed to return &m. Correct?

Comment: Yeah, that's correct. `m := matrix{}` notation returns a value not a pointer, so you would need to `return &m`.  `m := new(matrix)` creates a pointer to a matrix, so there you just need to `return m`. To quote the golang docs directly: "The expressions `new(File)` and `&File{}` are equivalent."